# Weird bitness issues using Python popen

Tags: python, r, subprocess, 32bit-64bit

So I call an external executable (`Rscript.exe` as part of [R portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/)) from Python `subprocess.popen`.

- Called from 32 bit python, it works.
- Called from 64 bit python, R complains that it can't find various packages, so something is different.

There shouldn't be any file system redirection going on (the path to `Rscript.exe` isn't in program files)

This could be a python issue, an R issue, or both.  Why does anything behave differently depending of the bitness of the process that called popen?  Can I force a call from 64 bit python to look like a 32 bit call from Rscript's perspective?

Comment: Can you post the code and the error messages please?

Comment: Is this on windows? why not use R64?

Comment: Please check the PATH, current directory and any library paths for the calls from the two pythons.

Comment: Using linux, I have encountered something similar. I fixed this using `system("sh -c 'unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH;executable'")` On windows, it could be that the PATH is set wrong, i.e. wrong DLLs are loaded

Comment: Update: solved.  this was not a bitness issue.  Popen was passing environment variables down to the subprocess.  I set `env={}` in the `Popen` call and it works now.

Comment: @SideshowBob Maybe update your question to make it a little more general, add that as an answer, and close it. Now it seems an esterile open question... could be a somewhat useful answered one ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you use subprocess.Popen class for sub programs or threads, it creates a pipe to shell or command prompt for the same and you can pass arguments to object of subprocess.Popen class as in form of string. That command runs in the shell and gets executed. 
So the error coming is neither a python issue, nor a R issue. 
Issue is there with your environment variables and system path.
You may not have saved the environment path for R, so is unable to get the Rscript.exe for execution.
And there is not file/directory redirection system directly available for searching folders/files for execution.

Set your system path variable for R and your problem will hopefully be solved